# If Java doesn't support parameterized type arrays, how does Arrays.asList() work with them?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

Supposedly, the method `Arrays.asList` looks like this:

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a)
```

`T...` is practically equivalent to `T[]`, but aren't arrays of generic types disallowed in Java? For example:

```
// Example 1
ArrayList<Integer>[] list = new ArrayList<Integer>[10];  // This is not allowed

// Example 2
List<ArrayList<Integer> > listOfList = Arrays.asList(new ArrayList<Integer>(), new ArrayList<Integer>());  // Allowed?
```

In example 2, the two parameters I passed would imply that `Arrays.asList` is taking `ArrayList<Integer>[]` as parameters which contradicts example 1. Why does example 2 work when example 1 doesn't?

Comment: Because the actual type of `T[]` is the erasure of the compile-time type. In this case the actual argument will always be an `Object[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare ageneric type array in Java which is perfectly legal. So this should work.

```
private E[] array;
```

But you can't instantiate a generic array like so, because arrays are reified and all the generic types are implemented as erasure. So this fictitious `E` is not available at runtime and you are out of luck !

```
array = new E[10];  // Illegal and gives compiler error.
```

But you have a workaround here. What you can do it just a cast.

```
array = (E[]) new Object[10];
```

This way you can create and instantiate a generic array in java. You may use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` at the lowest possible level, may be at the site of declaration to get rid of any unchecked warnings made by the compiler.

Comment: So can "unchecked or unsafe operations" be ignored (the message I get when compiling code like this)?

Answer (score 0):

Here, the `T[]` is in a parameter declaration, and as @Ravindra Ranwala answered, declaring a variable or parameter of type `T[]` is perfectly fine. It's *creating* an array of a type parameter type, i.e. `new T[]` that is not allowed.

In this case, by passing to the varargs argument, the compiler is actually implicitly creating an array of type `ArrayList<Integer>[]` to pass to the method. As you know, creating an array of a parameterized type, i.e. `new ArrayList<Integer>[]`, is also not allowed. So the compiler creates `new ArrayList[]`, and, normally, you would get a warning in a call such as this. However, you don't get a warning in this call because `Arrays.asList()` has the `@SafeVarargs` annotation, which indicates that they do not use the runtime component type of the array object, so it is safe.